# How could I export a Vector graphics in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

How could I export a Vector graphics of my model in Dymola? In Microsoft Visio OR AutoCAD software, I could find this kind of option under the menu of the file, but I couldn't find it in Dymola.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836734/getting-high-quality-pictures-from-dymola-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dymola can export .png or .svg images of the graphics layer.
Go to Tools, then click image, choose name and format.

[image]